# Pokemon Home Wonder Box Update

Tags: pokemon-home

Is there a way to update the Pokemon Home wonder box Pokemon without restarting the iPhone app? They only seem to get traded when the app restarts.

I've tried withdrawing a Pokemon to get it to refresh, and it took it out of the wonder box so I had to put it back in. All that did was reset the trade, so the other two got traded after I restarted the app and the one I took out didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's because I updated the app, but apparently if you wait long enough you'll start getting notifications about your Pokemon being wonder traded. You can then enter the wonder trade screen and you can see that the Pokemon have been traded out.

Restarting the app seems to trade them out in a fraction of the time, but waiting for the notifications works to trade them out as well.